# @ManyToMany association with other fields in the Join Table

Tags: many-to-many, doctrine-orm, symfony, entity-relationship

Under Symfony2, how to manage a Many-to-many association with additional fields in the joining table ?

For instance, I want to know which person uses a horse, and when. User and Horse have a many-to-many association and we store the date when this user rides that horse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the join table is more than just a join table, and in fact contains additional columns, than you don't have a ManyToMany anymore, but two OneToMany associations :

- a person has many rides
- a horse has many rides
- a ride has one person
- a ride has one horse

Comment: This is a surprising answer for me. It makes sense, but doesn't truely represent the actual ERD.